# how to call methods in java simultaneously?

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm working on a simple 2D text-base game. So, I have 2 *`Player`*  class thats fighting in a *`Arena`* class. I want to use them at the same time and modify their (position, hp, etc...)

For example: when program is running, *`Player1`* move to `x,y` position, *`Player2`* move to `x,y` position and then they have new position in *`Arena`* at the same time.

What's the best way to do this?

Comment: I think it would be easier achieved using a single thread - move all players (and do all other actions), update the screen, repeat.

Comment: I agree with you, but my task is: Players should  do their actions at the same time (in each round)

Comment: Define "same time"

Comment: There is no "same time". If you have a CPU with single core, only one operation can be executed at the same time. If you have more cores, you could have threads at the same time, but as far as i know, java does not let you decide which threads gets executed on which core. Even then the operating system might changes this (not even accounting for interrupts etc.). Usually games contain a so called "Game Loop" for logic/updates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't conflate game time with CPU time. Just because players move at the same game time doesn't mean you need to have CPU threads executing concurrently. You just need a logic loop that simulates simultaneous movement.

For example, loop over all the players and check that their actions don't conflict with each other. If two players want to move to the same location, show an error. Otherwise, loop over them a second time and move them all to their new locations. Then redraw the scene. Even though you're updating the players one at a time in the second loop, the screen won't show the movements until the entire scene is repainted.

Answer (score 0):

For this you must use thread. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25386839/how-can-i-call-methods-simultaneously-in-java) is an example of this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
new Thread() { 
    public void run() {
        method1();
    }
}.start();
new Thread() { 
    public void run() {
        method2();
    }
}.start();
//etc

//or, as kingdamian42 pointed out, if you use java8, use this
new Thread(() -> method1()).start();
new Thread(() -> method2()).start();}
```

here method one and two will be you players move.